# Redirect to login page after session timeout grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, session-variables, session-timeout

I am using `grails 2.3.4` and `spring security core 2.0 RC2` and `spring security ui 1.0 RC1`. Every thing is working fine but when ever there is session time out I get following error `"Error in grail layout main`" because I have called session variable in my layout's main.gsp file.Now I want to redirect to login page after every session timeout and dont show the error page.To redirect after session time out i have done it in `bootstrap.groovy` file as

```
def structureMap1 = Requestmap.findByUrl("/institution/index") ?: new Requestmap(url: "/institution/index",configAttribute: "ROLE_INSTITUTION").save(failOnError:true)
```

but there are so many pages so it is difficult to write for every page . Is there any other method to do it please help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using SecurityFilters you can place it in your conf folder:

```
class SecurityFilters {
    def filters = {
        catchRememberMeCookie(url: "/**") {
            before = {

                if (!session.user) {
                    def g = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib()
                    def confirmurl= g.createLink(controller: controllerName, action: actionName, params:params,  absolute: 'true' )
                    session.lastURL=request.getHeader('referer') ?: confirmurl

                    redirect(controller:'auth',action:'denied')
                    return false
                }
     }
}
```

This segment is an example and will not answer your question at hand since there is insufficient information to give a detailed answer but with a security filter - this sits above all your requests and if you need it to redirect to another location based on a specific value etc then you can so if no session.user do something else which will then kick in for all your actions